# replacing regex pattern in r

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a text column that contains speech to text records of phone calls between customers and agents. After some text manipulation on raw text values,  say I have a vector like below as an example:

`text <- " customer:customer text1 agent:agent text 1 customer:customer text2 agent:agent text 2`"

(Notice the space at the beginning of the vector *text*.)

Question: How can I extract customer and agent texts into two separate fields from the original source field (`text` vector in this case) ?

```
# desired outputs:
# field for customer texts
"customer text1, customer text2"
# field for agent texts
"agent text1, agent text2"
```

What I've could do so far (with limited experience on regex subject) is:

```
customerText <- gsub("^ customer:| agent:(.*)", "", text)
customerText 
[1] "customer text1"
```

EDIT:

Please consider below reproducable code for a dataframe based method, instead of above vector based one.

```
> callid <- c("1","2")
> conversation <- c(" customer:customer text 1 agent:agent text 1 customer:customer text 2 agent:agent text 2",
+                   " agent:agent text 8 customer:customer text 8 agent:agent text 9 customer:customer text 9")
> conversationCustomer <- c("customer text 1, customer text 2", "customer text 8, customer text 9")
> conversationAgent <- c("agent text 1, agent text 2", "agent text 8, agent text 9")
> df <- data.frame(callid, conversation)
> dfDesired <- data.frame(callid, conversation, conversationCustomer, conversationAgent)
> rm(callid, conversation, conversationCustomer, conversationAgent)
> 
> df
  callid                                                                             conversation
1      1  customer:customer text 1 agent:agent text 1 customer:customer text 2 agent:agent text 2
2      2  agent:agent text 8 customer:customer text 8 agent:agent text 9 customer:customer text 9
> dfDesired
  callid                                                                             conversation             conversationCustomer          conversationAgent
1      1  customer:customer text 1 agent:agent text 1 customer:customer text 2 agent:agent text 2 customer text 1, customer text 2 agent text 1, agent text 2
2      2  agent:agent text 8 customer:customer text 8 agent:agent text 9 customer:customer text 9 customer text 8, customer text 9 agent text 8, agent text 9
```

Thanks!

Comment: R for text parsing? God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- str_extract_all(text, "(?<=:)(customer\\s+\\w+\\s*\\d*)|(agent\\s+\\w+\\s*\\d*)")[[1]]
v1[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
v1[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
```

---

Or use `strsplit`

```
v1 <- strsplit(trimws(text), "(customer|agent):\\s*")[[1]]
v2 <- trimws(v1[nzchar(v1)])
toString(v2[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
toString(v2[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
```

Comment: above in the question, I gave the vector 'text' as example and your solution worked great for this. Thanks! However, when I tried ('strsplit' method) with real data on my dataframe it gaved the following error. > df$conversation_customer <- strsplit(trimws( df$conversation), "(customer|agent):\\s*")[[1]]
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, conversationCustomer , value = c("",  : 
  replacement has 86 rows, data has 1.  Then, with the help of your codes, I came up with:  df$conversationCustomer <- toString(strsplit(trimws(df$conversation), "(customer|agent):\\s*")[[1]][c(TRUE, FALSE)])

Comment: @kzmlbyrk  If it is a data.frame, then you don't need to subset the first element, ue sapply `lst <- strsplit(trimws(df$conversation), "(customer|agent):\\s*"); do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, function(x) x[nzchar(x)][c(TRUE, FALSE)]))` and similarly with `c(FALSE, TRUE)`

Comment: am I missing something?  df$conversationCustomer <- strsplit(trimws(df$conversation ), "(customer|agent):\\s*"); 
df$conversationCustomer <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df$conversationCustomer , function(x) x[nzchar(x)][c(TRUE, FALSE)])) gives the following: Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)    and the 'conversationCustomer' column only includes the first value.

Comment: another thing I've just realized: the column  'df$conversation' sometimes start with customer text and sometimes with agent text. So,  [c(TRUE, FALSE)]  statement may not filter the required text all the time. Sorry for realizing this situation late.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I could solve it as below. I guess it may be shortened by someone more experienced in regex.

```
df$conversationCustomer <- gsub("agent:.*?customer:", ",", df$conversation)  # replaces any text starting with "agent:" and ending with "customer:" and assigns the customer text to new variable.
df$conversationCustomer <- gsub("agent:.*", "", df$conversationCustomer) # this is for the agent texts at the end of conversation those I couldn't clean the "agent:" part using first regex 
df$conversationCustomer <- gsub("customer:", "", df$conversationCustomer) # this is for removing the "customer:" in the conversations those starts with customer text. (Again, I couldn't clean "customer:" part using first regex.)
df$conversationAgent <- gsub("customer:.*?agent:", ",", df$conversation)
df$conversationAgent <- gsub("customer:.*", "", df$conversationAgent)
df$conversationAgent <- gsub("agent:", "", df$conversationAgent)
```